# Using Nuxt Image Optimisation With Firebase Cloud storage

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

I employ Nuxt Image to reduce image sizes and quality.

Image URLs are obtained using nuxt server routes to obtain the download urls of the images.

In nuxt.config.ts, I've included the firebase storage domain as

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  image: {
    domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com']
  }
})
```

and using NuxtImg in the template

```js
<NuxtImg :src="image" />
```

Without the domain included, it works okay. but on the inclusion of the `firebasestorage.googleapis.com` to the domain, it gives an error of `400` without any message.

Update
[image: Screenshot of the error in the console]

Comment: What gives a `400` error?  Where are you seeing that error?  Any idea which code in your app is leading to that error?

Comment: @GregFenton Question has been updated with a screenshot of error message

Comment: Any idea why the URL it is requesting begins with `http://127.0.0.1:3000/....` ?  It looks like there is some prefix in the URL before the `https://firebasestorage.....`.  That is likely not expected.